# What game is this music from? (probably a Shoot 'em up)

Tags: gaming, identify-this-game, game-consoles, music

Back in my teenage years (around 1992) I recorded in VHS (but overrecorded it afterwards) a certain console game's opening sequence from a game TV show and attempted to transpose the background music to a MIDI file. Here is the converted MP3: https://ia601408.us.archive.org/29/items/GAMEUNKN/GAMEUNKN.mp3

I can't remember much of the opening itself (I paid more attention to the music at the time) but I can remember it had spacecraft in a space war setting, so I'm guessing it was a *[Shoot 'em up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoot_%27em_up)*.

I assume the song was from a [Sega Genesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_System) (branded *Sega Megadrive* here in Brazil) game or some 8-bit console released here at the time ([NES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nintendo_Entertainment_System), [Master System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_System)). It could also be a [TurboGrafx-16](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/TurboGrafx-16) game (*PC Engine* outside North America).

I've been trying to identify that particular song and game for years. Hope someone can help, even though the transposal is not particularly accurate.

Comment: I don't recognise it but I know how annoying it can be when you don't know the title. I really hope you find the answer to this.

Comment: It *does* sound like shmup music and at least some of those progressions sound familiar, though possibly in a different key. I haven't seen many shmups though. Have you already checked Life Force and the Gradius and Parodius series?

Comment: Just to confirm: that's an MP3 of the MIDI transcription of the original? So no point looking for clues in terms of "which chip could generate this?"?

Comment: @Tommy Yes, it is an MP3 of a MIDI transcription made by ear.

Comment: @ssokolow I did check Gradius and Parodius, and just checked Life Force, but it's not that one. But thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I just changed it to a gofile.io link. Hope that is okay.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I'm sorry, I wasn't quite attentive. Now I have uploaded it to archive.org; I think it is good now. Otherwise please let me know and I'll try something else.

Comment: There’s some similarity to the [Airwolf](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3C6Qq3tknXc) theme ([C64/SID rendition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uWrfyJTIcds)), as well as maybe the [Frontier: Elite II](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbegNmKRZUM) theme ([another version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NzveVFilqMU)) but I don’t think those are similar _enough_...

Comment: @Piovezan Good thinking; I forgot you could just _upload_ stuff to the Internet Archive!

Answer (score 1):

I don't instantly recognise it, but it's quite similar to the style of the Thunderforce III and Thunderforce IV horizontal scrollers, and I definitely recall rocking-out to both of those.

Comment: I checked, it's not any of those. Thanks for the suggestions, though.